# How can I return only one record per type?

Tags: sql, teradata, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with multiple records per one account type and I want to return only one by latest date. I have:

```
SELECT
id_nbr AS ID,
contact_type AS contype,
last_update AS date
FROM table
WHERE (contact_type = 'AAA' OR contact_type = 'BBB' OR contact_type = 'CCC');
```

It may return something like this:

```
ID          contype     date
111111111   AAA         2020-01-30
111111111   AAA         2019-05-05 
111111111   BBB         2020-01-02
111111111   CCC         2020-02-17
```

Looking at this data, I only want 3 rows because contype has multiple AAA records but I only want the latest date. Something like:

```
ID          contype     date
111111111   AAA         2020-01-30
111111111   BBB         2020-01-02
111111111   CCC         2020-02-17
```

This is obviously very high-level but how can I achieve this? This would help me tremendously. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: DISTINCT, GROUP BY

Comment: Check out window functions.

Comment: Is the ID value always 111111111? Or just poor sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `qualify`:

```
SELECT id_nbr AS ID, contact_type AS contype, last_update AS date
FROM table
WHERE contact_type IN ('AAA', 'BBB' , 'CCC')
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY contact_type ORDER BY last_update DESC) = 1;
```

This returns the most recent row for each type.

Comment: This worked :) Thank you very much. I will accept this answer in 5 minutes (due to constraints).

Answer (score 1):

```
-- create a new column (temp_tab) with max date and
-- select the rows where the date is equal to temp_tab


select ID, contype, date from
(select ID, contype, date, max(date) over (partition by ID, contype) as temp_tab from table)
where date = temp_tab
```

Comment: I would actually comment outside of your code - make sure people understand what and why.